# Configuring SMTP in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, smtp

I have successfully configured a virtual SMTP server in Windows Server 2008 using [this guide](http://www.cmsconnect.com/praetor/webhelpg2/chapter_2_-_pre-installation_considerations/Configuring_the_SMTP_Server.htm).

After setting the relay it successfully sent email, but how do I create an email account that can be added to Outlook so that I can start receiving email? I assume the default account is my account name "administrator@domain.com", but when I add it to Outlook it shows an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating Outlook Account for an Exchanger Server, if using email address failed for what ever reason, we can use manual configuration.

There is detail steps [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/outlook-help/add-or-remove-an-e-mail-account-HA001231634.aspx#BM3) from Microsoft. I will outline below:

- Basically we are not using autodiscovery (which is base on the email address, which is failing)
- Start Creating an Outlook profile/account for Exchange as before
- After you click **Microsoft Exchange, POP3, IMAP or HTTP account** and **next**
- Check mark **Manually configure server settings or additional server types**

The rest should be straight forward.

One more note when entering username, it is the **WindowsLoginName** OR **Domain\WindowsLoginName**. If first one doesn't work, try the second format.